# How do I throw an error for my singleton class?

Tags: php, error-handling

This is the singleton pattern also named as the singleton class.  Its goal is to allow only one object of type singleton.  If there is already one and I call it, I'd like it to error out in some way.  This won't happen in production but in development.  Is there a better way then just saying echo echo "Error:only one connection";

```
class singleton
  {
  protected static $_db_pointer = NULL;
  private function __construct()
    {
    $this->_db_pointer = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    }
  public static function get_instance()
    {
    if(self::$_db_pointer == NULL)
      {
      return new self();
      } 
    else
      {
      echo "Error:only one connection";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: May I ask why you're going for a singleton if you're essentially avoiding it? If you're trying to cut down on the numbers of times you call it by flagging it, that's one thing. But to go to the trouble of making a singleton only to avoid it at certain costs seems....inefficient.

Comment: Do *not* call your singleton class "singleton". Its chief job isn't (I hope) to be a singleton. Call it what it actually does.

Comment: I have a class database which extends it and then multiple classes which extend beyond this. However I did find that each separate user will create a separate singleton object so it limits to one database connection per user. It is superfulous in that I could simply make sure that I don't open a database connection more then once. I can add the database class if needed so it is clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions usually are better.

```
else
{
  throw new Exception("Error:only one connection");
}
```

You can also use "LogicException", "RuntimeException", and a few others.

Further reading:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Another approach with singleton class is just to return the object instead of creating a new instance if one exists.

Comment: Do I have to set up a try and catch block as well?

Comment: Only if you are interested in suppressing or chaining the error somewhere else. Otherwise an uncaught exception will just turn into a Fatal Error and the person using your class will get the message.

Comment: @Chris Aaker: yes, on code calling Singleton::getInstance() - unless you want the script to 'die' with that exception.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented the singleton pattern correctly. Had you done so, the error condition to which you refer could not exist.

Combining the [PHP documentation's singleton example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton) and the original code gives:

```
class singleton
{
    // Hold an instance of the class
    private static $instance;
    private static $db_pointer;

    // A private constructor; prevents direct creation of object
    private function __construct() {
        $this->_db_pointer = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);        
    }

    // The singleton method
    public static function get_instance() 
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getDbPointer() {
        return self::$db_pointer;
    }


    // Prevent users to clone the instance
    public function __clone() {
        trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of using $instance to keep track of their being an instance..I simplified it. Because anytime there is an instance, a link to a database is created - $_db_pointer, I used this variable to determine wether or not an instance has already been created.